# How to run WCF IPC (http) on localhost without requesting administrative privileges?

Tags: windows, wcf, security, ipc, communication

We're developing a set of applications that need to communicate with each other on the user's session. These applications do not require any administrative privileges to run, but as soon as one of them tries to open an http listener - it fails due to lack of the administrative credentials. On the other hand, since user doesn't have any admin rights, he can't configure an HTTP ACL as well.

Is there any way to allow http/REST communication between the processes on a localhost inside the non-administrative user session?

Example of the apps: a tray app plays a role of a service and multiple sticky-note apps talking to it to save data.

Does it means that Microsoft forces me to use ONLY Named Pipes for IPC in the local user session if the user doesn't have admin rights (can't install with the admin rights)?

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally done this, but I would think that you'd need to do the HTTP namespace/ACL registration in an installer which is running with administrative priviledges.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dos command:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8083/path1 user=USERNAME
```

NOTE: replace the port, the path and the USERNAME with your own

Comment: If you run netsh - you need admin rights.  This is the error you'll get without them:

Url reservation add failed, Error: 5
The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator)